# how to select desired country in bootsratp country picker?

Tags: bootstrapping, country-codes

The below code shows US flag and US is selected when the drop down is loaded.

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true"></div>
```

[image]

I want to selecte UK in a form and Iraq in another form but when tried below it does not show flags of the country and the country name.

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="UK" data-flags="true"></div>
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="IRQ" data-flags="true"></div>
```

The above code selected is blank by default.

[image]
How can I show UK and Iraq flag as how US name and flag are selected on `<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true"></div>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

- for UK, use `data-country="GB"`
- for Iraq, use `data-country="IQ"`

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you should add links to CSS and JS files of Bootstrap Form Helpers library which should be previously downloaded on your server

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap-form-helpers.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"></script>
```

---

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true">
</div>
```

**Example for displaying the country name and flag from a country code**

```
<span class="bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true"></span>
```

Read more about it
http://www.freenetmall.com/common/jquery/FormHelpers/docs/country.html